# 1 dimensional array to string error

Tags: arrays, vb.net

The program keeps showing me the "Wrong username" msgbox. I compare "navn" against file. I write the right username and password, but the msgbox keeps popping up

```
Dim R As IO.StreamReader
Dim LogInSom As String
Dim Navn As String
Dim Kode As String
Dim OKnavn As Boolean
Dim Kode2 As String
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Navn = InputBox("Write your username")
    Dim directorry = "C:\Klub-Oversigt\Spillere\"
    Dim filees() As System.IO.FileInfo
    Dim dirinffo As New System.IO.DirectoryInfo(directorry)
    filees = dirinffo.GetFiles("*", IO.SearchOption.AllDirectories)
    For Each file In filees
        If Navn Is file Then
            OKnavn = True
            Exit For
        Else

            OKnavn = False

        End If
    Next
    Kode = InputBox("Write your pass")

    If OKnavn = True Then
        R = New IO.StreamReader("C:\Klub-Oversigt\Spillere\" & Navn & ".txt")
        Kode2 = R.ReadToEnd()
        R.Close()
        If Kode Is Kode2 Then
            MsgBox("Kode og brugernavn accepteret!", MsgBoxStyle.Information)
        Else
            MsgBox("Wrong pass!")
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox("Wrong username." & Chr(13) & "Hvis du er sikker på du har skrevet rigtigt, kan du være banned", MsgBoxStyle.Critical, "Fejl!")
        End
    End If
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Navn` is a `String`, `file` is a [`FileInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  You need to compare `Navn` with `file.Name`.

Specifically, you need to use the comparison operator for equality (`=`).  You're improperly using the [`Is` operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kb136x1y.aspx) which checks *reference equality* and that's not what you want in this case.

Also, the string comparison between the user input and the filenames fails to account for the `.txt` extension that will be present on each filename.

Comment: Revised my answer; use the `=` operator for value comparisons.

Comment: It still show me the msgbox when i write username and pass.

Comment: Remember, the filename is going to include the `.txt` extension.  If the username does not include ".txt" at the end, the two will never match.

Comment: I'm not sure what u are talking about

Comment: It might help you to add this line inside the for each loop: `MsgBox(Navn & " =? " & file.Name)`

Comment: Thank you. My program works. But i removed the `MsgBox(Navn & "=? " & file.name)`